# Data from the object php

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I have a object that creates `simplexml_load_file();`

```
$xmlPoland = simplexml_load_file('http://export.yandex.ru/weather-ng/forecasts/12375.xml');

echo "<pre>";
print_r($xmlPoland);
echo "</pre>";
```

I need to get the value of the `[fact] temperature`(`-9`).

How to make this?

Comment: There are many temperature elements with different parents, representing the temperature throughout various parts of the day.  Which one are you trying to get?  What have you tried so far?  Have you checked out http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php ?

Comment: [fact] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [source] => forecast
                )

            [observation_time] => 2014-12-29T19:06:19
            [uptime] => 2014-12-29T19:06:19
            [temperature] => -9
            [weather_condition] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [code] => mostly-clear
                        )

                )

Comment: I need the actual temperature [fact]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
echo $xmlPoland->fact->temperature;
```

Output:

```
-9
```

If you need it from this part:

```
[fact] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [@attributes] => Array
            (
                [source] => forecast
            )

        [observation_time] => 2014-12-29T19:06:19
        [uptime] => 2014-12-29T19:06:19
        [temperature] => -9
        [weather_condition] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [code] => mostly-clear
                    )

            )
```

Also i would recommend you to take a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php

And as @superultranova suggested take a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php